# Python: Programmatically resize .jpgs

Tags: java, c++, python, resize, jpeg

I have a folder of .jpgs files that are all over 2MB in size. I need to upload them to a website but they are WAY too large to show on a website.

Is there a way to resize the actual images in Python &/or to reduce the file size of the jpgs in python.

**Maybe there is a native python library to work with bitmaps &/or jpegs or maybe there is a third party library to do this?**

PS: I also know Java & C++, are there any functions(or 3rd party libraries) in those languages that could do this?

Comment: If you just want the problem solved, [ImageMagick's `convert` command](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/convert.php) makes this kind of operation trivially easy. If you want the fun of programming it, [Python's PIL](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/) is a good place to start.

Answer (score 7):

Can't get much easier than with [PIL](http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/introduction.htm):

```
from PIL import Image

size = 300, 300
im = Image.open('image.jpg') 
im.thumbnail(size, Image.ANTIALIAS) # thumbnail maintains aspect ratio
im.save('image_resized.jpg')
```

Comment: +1 for PIL, the only bad thing is no Python 3 support yet

Comment: Yeah, PIL is pretty crucial. I've seen a few ports of it to Python 3.x, no clue how well they work though. Hopefully get official Python 3.x support soon.

Comment: check out Pillow.  It is a fork of PIL, with better packaging... and it now supports Python 3.  https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow/2.0.0

Answer (score 0):

This will solve the problem, overwriting all files with the new size:

```
import cv2
import os

size=50
folder='/home/user/anaconda3/images'

for filename in os.listdir(folder):
    img = cv2.imread(os.path.join(folder,filename), cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    img2=cv2.resize(img,(size,size))
    cv2.imwrite('/home/user/anaconda3/images/'+filename,img2)
```